Python generating usable currency for pivot table on excel
I generate a report using python that has a column of rates. These rates used to be just floats that I would convert using the number formatter on excel to currency and use that column for a pivot table. I wanted to automate this for the future so less manual work would be needed and also didn't want to use VBA since if I have to handoff this report the next person might not know VBA. I also know that with how the pivot tables need to look, I cannot generate them from python and need to manually generate them from excel. This will not change.
I tried using the formatter .map('${:,.2f}'.format) but this causes the values to be identical to string values. When I use this formatter, I have to highlight the values, convert to number, then convert to currency. I pretty much causing myself more work.
for example,
table = [
    ['a',  '1.2',  '4.2' ],
    ['b',  '70',   '0.03'],
    ['x',  '5',    '0'   ],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])

def format_currency(value):
    try:
        value = float(value)
        return '${:,.2f}'.format(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].apply(format_currency)
df['Column3'] = df['Column3'].apply(format_currency)

let's say we want the all the numbers above to be currency, I could do the above but excel doesn't really view these values as currency.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi, welcome to SO! It's unclear to me what the actual problem is. So, you have a pd.DataFrame with a column that contains some currencies (floats): what needs to happen to them? Please provide a [mre]. Also, please include your own attempt. It will help people understand your question better.

@ouroboros1 these floats are used to create a pivot table. I just was hoping there would be a way to convert the floats to currency directly from python instead of having to highlight the column and use the number formatter in excel AFTER the report is generated. Like I wanted the formatting part to be done when the script is ran.

Excel does not view anything as "currency", it may format something as currency. E.g., if you enter 1 in A1 and then format it as currency, it keeps being the number 1, it just looks like $1.00. Do you mean that you want to write some floats to Excel, and that upon opening that Excel file, the floats should be formatted as currencies?

@ouroboros1 Exactly! Basically so I don't have to format it to currency by myself through the excel number formatter.
